# Issue with fxLayout after refresh

Tags: angular, typescript, flexbox, angular-material

I have a issue with fxLayout when refresh the page its too slow to show the HTML of page

Does it look like this for more than 10 seconds

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44qyS.jpg)

Comment: with refresh you mean a hard-refresh / browser refresh or just navigation withing the app.

Comment: with both action happened